# Fantasy book series. Boy raised by herbalist travels with a dragon lady

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this in high school, some time between 2018-2020. I believe there was something related to dragons in the title or cover art. The book was in English and I cannot remember any character names.

The main character was in his late teens and is raised by his grandfather/father who is a healer/herbalist. The character has a triangle mark(?) and he is supposedly the chosen one because his mark has all powers of the other marks (warrior, healer, and crafter).

The main character's father also had the triangle mark and was super distraught because his son had the mark as well which meant all that he did, did not resolve the big issue and he died shortly after that in battle. Both of the main character's parents are deceased.

Healers are able to heal wound by mending. They tend to be very sappy as the grandfather says, but when the main character heals someone he envisions it as mending a crack in a clay pot (wet clay) which combines his healer and crafter powers without him realizing. Crafter are able to manipulate materials when making something.

At some point a dragon lady (who can transform into a dragon) comes and finds him and they go off on an adventure to awaken his latent powers. In order to awaken his warrior talent, the dragon lady takes him to a village where he learns to fight, and during that time the main character and the dragon lady fall in love and I believe at some point they get married.

Also a big plot point in the series is when the main character frees a bunch of giants who were enslaved and they make him a bed. The giants did this as a way of showing thanks because they do not say thank you if they could repay the favor, and the main character had stood up for another giant and taken that giant's lashes for him, and when the lady transformed it was into a big dragon.

A scene I distinctly remember is the main character is doing work on a farming field and gets whipped by one of the slavers with a magic/enchanted whip, and instead of hurting him and cause him to feel slimy where the whip hit him. Also on another occasion when he was whipped with a whip that had sharp rocks on it, he was able to transform his back into stone to defend himself.

At one point the bad guy was able to corrupt another dragon that was sealed. This sealed dragon was called something along the lines of "the Black Dragon" and its human form was that of a 10-years-old child, roughly.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Read it between 2018-2020 i belive there was something related to dragons in the title or cover art. Also a big plot point in the series is when the main character frees a bunch of giants who were enslaved and they make him a bed.

Comment: @Gavin - I've edited that info into the question. Can you recall anything else? What was the main character's name? How old were they? Was there any over sex/violence in the book or was it aimed at youngsters? Were there any words that were unusual used to describe the powers? How did they awaken his latent powers? In what way was the lady a dragon?

Comment: The main character was in his late teens, there was a decent amount of violence, and in order to awaken his latent talent the dragon lady took him to village and had the village warriors train. The lady can transform into a dragon. Also the bad guy was able to corrupt another dragon that was sealed and the sealed dragon was called something along the lines of the black dragon and its human form was that of 10 year child roughly

Comment: Do you recall anything else? What language was the book in? What was the female character's name? When she transformed was it into a large dragon or just something human-sized? Where was the triangular mark on his body? How did the powers manifest (e.g. what can a healer do, how do they do it)? How and why did the giants make him a bed?

Comment: The giants made him a bed as a way of showing thanks because they didnt say thank you if they could repay the favor, and the main character stood up for another giant and took that giants lashes for him, and when the lady transformed it was into a big dragon. The book was in English and i cant remember any character names. Healers are able to heal wound by mending and healers tend to be very sappy as the grandfather says, but when the main character heals someone he envisions it as mending a crack in a clay pot(wet clay) which combines his healer and crafter powers without him realizing

Comment: Also during their time at the village the main character and the dragon lady fall in love and i do belive they get married. Also the main characters father also had the triangle mark and was super distraught because his son had the mark as well which meant all that he did, didnt resolve the big issue and he died shortly after that in battle. Both of the main characters parents are deceased.

Answer (score 3):

*Harbinger* (2012) by Shae Ford, first book of the *Fate's Forsaken* quadrilogy.

Summary of the first book, from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18918883-harbinger):

> Seventeen years ago, a long and bloody rebellion wracked the six united regions of the Kingdom. Now the new King wields the vast and unvanquished army of Midlan with his right hand, and with his left has granted a small group of thugs — the nobles he calls his Sovereign Five — unbridled rule over the other regions. As if this weren’t bad enough, **the King has also outlawed the practice of whispering — which is a problem for Kael.**
>
> It's not like he asked to be born a whisperer: **he didn’t ask for his strange healing powers** anymore than he asked to be the village runt. And when he rescues a wounded girl from the perils of the Unforgivable Mountains, his luck only gets worse. She couldn’t have been just any girl: she had to be Kyleigh —the sword-wielding renegade knight with all of Midlan on her trail. **Then one miserable, snowy evening, things go from bad to worse, and Kael is left with no choice but to follow Kyleigh down the mountains and into the tumultuous lowlands. She leads him on one mad quest after the next** — eventually pulling off an act of such mischievous proportions that it threatens to change the Kingdom as they know it.

Several other matches:

- [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1837020818) confirms that Kyleigh is a dragon:

> During the story Kael makes friends with various types who accompany him on these quests. In book 1 **Kyleigh (a dragon shifter)** has a major role.

- [The second book's cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7In23.jpg) features a huge snake-like body and [Amazon's summary of it](https://www.amazon.fr/Slight-Shadow-Shae-Ford/dp/0692631380) has a bit about giants and slavery:

> He finds himself trapped in Gilderick's clutches and **forced to work as a slave, laboring alongside the giants** -- who don't exactly welcome him.

- [This review of the third book](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1900902203) mentions a wedding between the main characters:

> But dang Kael is so savage when it comes to Kyleigh. **Tormenting her to ask him to marry her because she hurts his feelings when he asked her.**  [...] **The wedding scene at the end.** My lord! I couldn't help but scream with happiness.

---

Found with the Google query `fantasy book healer dragon mark hand site:goodreads.com/book`, although it eventually felt *very* familiar and it turned out I had previously identified it for [Young adult fantasy trilogy about a boy with healing powers and a girl who is really a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243627/). That question also mentioned the main character having "a symbol in his eyes that signifies he has special powers".